# How do I avoid the circular argument reference warning in activesupport

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport

How do I avoid the circular argument reference warning in activesupport. Happens on ruby 2.2.0

```
/home/ec2-user/apps/foo_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now
/home/ec2-user/apps/foo_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ruby-ole-1.2.11.7/lib/ole/types/base.rb:265: warning: duplicated key at line 266 ignored: 4095
```

Comment: Separate issue - in my case, i was re-initialising instance variables in sub-classes and super classes in a circular  way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [compass](https://github.com/Compass/compass) issue [here](https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1902). They haven't release new version yet so you may need to wait for it.

Comment: this is precisely the issue yet, it can be fixed by installing the latest version of compass after uninstalling the current version. Please refer my answer for the steps.

Comment: It sounds very much like the Compass issue is for a different circular argument reference from the one in ActiveSupport.

Answer (score 17):

Use Rails 3.2.22

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.22'
```

OR

warning fixes in version 1.2.11.8:

```
bundle update ruby-ole
```

Answer (score 12):

This is an issue of Active Support and has been fixed with these two commits:

- https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/8fd52705eda6a2cd7e9a8a5bc723fa094e359eb7
- https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/3a30b12c774dfaa72acfe520e823374131631ea9

Unfortunately, these commits have been never included into the 3.2 releases,
because the current last release (v3.2.21) was out on 18 Nov 2014 
and *after that* these commits were merged.

If you don't want to see this warning message *definitely*, you should change
your `Gemfile` like this:

```
# gem 'rails', '3.2.21'
gem 'rails', git: 'https://github.com/rails/rails.git', branch: '3-2-stable'
```

Otherwise, you should downgrade ruby to 2.1 or wait the release of v3.2.22,
which won't come until a grave security hole is found.

After all, there is no easy way to avoid this issue. Changing `Gemfile`
for such a trivial annoyance may be an overreaction in my view.
It will delay your deployment process quite a lot.

Comment: 3.2.22 is now out with this fix made.

Comment: @Hisham Thanks for the update. The release announcement is here:  http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2015/6/16/Rails-3-2-22-4-1-11-and-4-2-2-have-been-released-and-more/

Comment: So I'm guessing it would now be suggested to fix the Gemfile with `gem 'rails', '3.2.22'` (as per shilovk's answer) rather than rely on the Git repo. (And of course by now, to consider upgrading the site to a later version of Rails that isn't 7 years old...)

Answer (score 10):

I was not using compass in my application Based on this post [here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/6873211) I upped my Rails version from 4.1.1 to 4.1.9 which worked.

Answer (score 3):

here is what i did to resolve that, i had the latest ruby and the gems are not compatible with that, so after having a fight for nearly a day i switched to older ruby version using rvm

from ruby-2.2.1 to ruby-2.0.0  ,

again this is not an issue with ruby version but incompatibility with gems,try and have good luck with that.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Here is a solution to this:
Try doing all these changes in your .rbenv/.rvm folder and change in these files:

https://github.com/tmm1/rails/commit/8fd52705eda6a2cd7e9a8a5bc723fa094e359eb7

Answer (score 1):

Hypothetically, updating to Rails 4.2.0 - which you should be able to do via the following commands - should fix this error, although it hasn't worked for me:

```
rvm use ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2 --create
gem install rails 
rails -v
```

I'm getting the same "circular argument error" message as well (I posted more about my failed attempts to fix it here, will update if I find an answer: [Rails gem update not working (version 4.1.1 to 4.2.0) as a solution to "warning: circular argument reference" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28824040/rails-gem-update-not-working-version-4-1-1-to-4-2-0-as-a-solution-to-warning/28824114#28824114)).

Answer (score 1):

I altered the time_zone.rb file, instead of `now=now`, I entered `now=Time.now` and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue as well, you can use the following steps to resolve it (worked for me).

```
$ gem uninstall compass
$ gem update --system
$ gem install compass
```