# What is a "circular argument reference" error, with activesupport time_zone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rails-migrations

I'm new in ruby on rails, and I am trying to create a tutorial. I have a problem when I execute `rake db:migrate`.

```
hugo@ubuntu:~/pin_board$ rake db:migrate
/home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:283: warning: circular argument reference - now
```

What causes this?
Can somebody help me?

Comment: It is hard to help you in this way.. Need deep debugging..

Comment: Attach your migrations, please.

Comment: I open migration folder and find this:

class AddUserIdToPins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :pins, :user_id, :integer
    add_index :pins, :user_id
  end
end

Comment: You executed rails db:migrate or rake db:migrate?

Comment: Sorry I wrote bad. I executed rake db:migrate, and appear this bug, but then i excecute: rails g migration add_user_id_to_pins user_id:integer:index and appear again this bug

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with migrations. Run `bundle update` and try again, if that doesn't work, try using a different version of rails Incidentally, what version of rails are you using?

Comment: I think you need to run `bundle update` may be there is issue with rails version.

Comment: I run bundle update buy appear same bug. Im using 4.0.5. Should I try another Rails version?

Comment: yeah, try 4.2, it's a rails dependencies problem, not a rake problem.

Comment: Ok, one question. How I repleace Rails version? I ve seen rails documentation, and how install rails, but i dont find how install an specific version like 4.2.  Sorry for muy questions  Im new in this world. And thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 26):

You see this warning message because your Rails version is 4.0.5. The issue has been fixed on Rails 4.0.6.

Update your `Gemfile` and run `bundle update rails`.

If you want to know the background of this issue, read my answer to another question https://stackoverflow.com/a/30733016/513554.

Comment: Same goes for Rails 3. Not sure which version it got fixed in but after upgrading from `3.2.19` to `3.2.22` it was fixed.

Comment: I had the problem with `3.2.19`, then tried `3.2.20` and `3.2.21`, it didn't work. `3.2.22` worked fine.