# Ruby 2.2.2 - Time zone reference

Tags: ruby, timezone

I just upgraded to Ruby v 2.2.2.

Now, when I start my console, I get this error:

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:282: warning: circular argument reference - now
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.2)
```

I don't know what it means or how to fix it. I don't have a file called time_zone.rb in my application, so I assume its something that is incorporated by reference.

Does anyone know what to do to resolve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I avoid the circular argument reference warning in activesupport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27717309/how-do-i-avoid-the-circular-argument-reference-warning-in-activesupport)

Comment: Hi Jordan - I don't think this is the same problem. I don't know what compass is and I don't use it, and I'm trying to work on Ruby 2.2.2. not 2.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you are using Rails in your project. You just need to upgrade your Rails version to 4.1.9.

This issue was fixed in these commits:

- [fix ruby 2.2 warning: circular argument reference](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/8fd52705eda6a2cd7e9a8a5bc723fa094e359eb7)
- [use self.method syntax to resolve circular argument issues](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/3a30b12c774dfaa72acfe520e823374131631ea9)

You can upgrade the Rails version in your Gemfile or Gemfile.lock files.

**Gemfile**

```
gem "rails", "4.1.9"
```

**Gemfile.lock**

```
rails (4.1.9)
```

Be sure to run `bundle` after you make these changes!

Comment: Not a chance, buddy! Rails dropped the ActiveRecord::Base.silence method after 4.0.0. How do I shut this thing up?

Comment: For what it's worth, updating rails from `3.2.21` to `3.2.22.5` got rid of this warning for me.